# Good way of ignoring \draw, \fill or \node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, transparency

I know three ways how to "ignore", or at least "hide" something in Ti*k*Z using `[...]` or `\tikzset{bla/.style={...}}`:

- `[draw=none]` (works like charm for `\draw`, but doesn't work for `node` contents;
- `[white]` (works for all, but covers other things, the text is still present and copy-pastable);
- `[text opacity=0]` (works for all, but implies PDF with transparency, and the text is still present and copy-pastable).

So: Is there really no solution how to make the drawings (especially nodes) completely disappear? It is required to work with `\tikzset{bla./style={...}}`.

A MWE to play with:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
\draw (0,0) -- (2,2);
\draw[draw=none] (0,1) -- (2,3);
\node at (3,3) {BLA};
\node[white] at (3,4) {BLA};
\node[text opacity=0] at (3,5) {BLA};
\node[blue,draw,rectangle] at (7,3) {FOO};
\node[blue,draw,rectangle,draw=none,text opacity=0] at (7,4) {FOO};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about `%`? ;)

Comment: Or `\phantom{…}`?

Comment: @HenriMenke My automatically generated code has 462 TikZ instructions and 240kB of code. The instructions use a small set of TikZ keys, and I need to enable or disable this or that to see different features of the figure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way is to define a `ignore` style using `execute at begin node` and `execute at end node` to box the contents and not to use the box; the advantage here is that you can ignore all kind of material (see the example with an image):

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox\mybox
\tikzset{
  ignore/.style={
    execute at begin node={\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}},
    execute at end node={\end{lrbox}}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xshift=20cm]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
\draw[draw=none] (0,0) -- (2,2);
\draw[draw=none] (0,1) -- (2,3);
\node[ignore] at (3,3) {BLA};
\node[ignore] at (3,4) {BLA};
\node[ignore] at (3,5) {BLA};
\node[blue,draw=none,rectangle,ignore] at (7,3) {FOO};
\node[blue,rectangle,draw=none,ignore] at (7,4) {FOO};
\node[blue,rectangle,draw=none,ignore] at (7,4) {FOO};
\node[ignore] at (5,5) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

You could change `ignore` to

```
  ignore/.style={
    execute at begin node={\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}},
    execute at end node={\end{lrbox}},
    draw=none,
    fill=none
  }
```

and then you can also ignore `\draw`, or `\filldraw` (or similar) using the style:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox\mybox
\tikzset{
  ignore/.style={
    execute at begin node={\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}},
    execute at end node={\end{lrbox}},
    draw=none,
    fill=none
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xshift=20cm]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
\draw[draw=red,ignore] (0,0) -- (2,2);
\filldraw[draw=red,fill=blue,ignore] (4,4) rectangle ++(2,2);
\draw[draw=blue,ignore] (0,1) -- (2,3);
\node[ignore] at (3,3) {BLA};
\node[ignore] at (3,4) {BLA};
\node[ignore] at (3,5) {BLA};
\node[blue,fill=blue,rectangle,ignore] at (7,3) {FOO};
\node[blue,rectangle,ignore] at (7,4) {FOO};
\node[blue,rectangle,ignore] at (7,4) {FOO};
\node[ignore] at (5,5) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
\draw[draw=none] (0,0) -- (2,2);
\draw[draw=none] (0,1) -- (2,3);
\node[font=\nullfont] at (3,3) {BLA};
\node[font=\nullfont] at (3,4) {BLA};
\node[font=\nullfont] at (3,5) {BLA};
\node[blue,draw=none,rectangle,font=\nullfont] at (7,3) {FOO};
\node[blue,rectangle,draw=none,font=\nullfont] at (7,4) {FOO};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A TikZ answer by David?!  My upvote is all yours!